How to create cross tab report 2 level columns crystal report?
I work on crystal report I face issue I can't make two LEVEL columns header meaning on cross tab I can't categorize data two levels.
So, I need first header column ADV_IS_LOCAL_DESC.
then under it will use header for columns AREA_DESC
And rows will be field COMPANY_TYPE_DESC
And summary will be field COMPANY_TYPE_DESC
and rows will be ADV_Count
Data Input

and output will be

Important update
I need number of features columns on two tabs to be equal
I see second tab 4 columns
but on first tab 2 columns
can I have number of features distinct


You should be able to specify ADV_IS_LOCAL_DESC as the first column field and  AREA_DESC as the second column field.
If there's a problem, please describe what happens when you try to follow those steps.

only small notes i need number of features to be same on two tabs so can you help me on that

check post update
